# sequelize bulkinsert to jsonb[] error with invalid value or missed type

Tags: escaping

I have a column which is `jsonb[]`, and I am trying to seed data using `buldInsert` with `queryInterface` in `Sequelize`.

**What I have tried:**

Option: 1

```
...
columnName: [
      JSON.stringify({ name: "Chicken", addition: 1 }),
      JSON.stringify({ name: "Shrimp", addition: 3 }),
      JSON.stringify({ name: "Tofu", addition: 0 }),
    ],
...
```

> Error: Cannot pass text[] to jsonb[]

Option: 2

```
...
columnName: [
      { name: "Chicken", addition: 1 },
      { name: "Shrimp", addition: 3 },
      { name: "Tofu", addition: 0 },
    ],
...
```

> Error: Invalid value

What else could I try here?

Answer (score 3):

Try passing a fourth argument to `bulkInsert` like so:

```
const myRows = [
  {
    myColumn: "Mark",
    myJsonColumn: { prop: 4 },
  },
  // ...
];

await queryInterface.bulkInsert(
  "MyTable",
  myRows,
  {},
  { myJsonColumn: { type: new Sequelize.JSON() } }
);
```

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8310#issuecomment-430287656

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, but with `model.bulkCreate()`:

```
const accountsData = [
    { id: 1, payload: JSON.stringify({ sub_field: subField }) },
    { id: 2, payload: JSON.stringify({ sub_field: subField }) },
    { id: 3, payload: JSON.stringify({ sub_field: subField }) },
]

await this.accountModel.bulkCreate({ data: accountsData });
```

`payload` is `JSONB` field and `subFieldOne` and `subFieldTwo` its subfields